# Button with image and text centered

Tags: android, image, button

I need button with text in the middle and icon left of text.

my button :

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick=""
            android:text="@string/search_button"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/new_star_nonactive" />
```

I need button with width fill_parent (all screen width)

but I have this :
[image]

How can I set image position center, near the text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Then only way to do that, is to use padding. In your case you want the image to move to the right, so use `android:paddingLeft="50dp"` or the amount of dips you want to move.

EDIT:
also add `android:gravity="left | center"` in order to get the text right with the image.

Comment: but i dont know what padding.. on different screens it will be different

Comment: well mate, that's the only way to do it. Also, I think when specifying the dips in the xml and not in Java code, android respects that, not 100 % sure though.

Comment: or if you want to be sure, you can create different layouts for different screens and put them in layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi etc etc.

Comment: padding will be applicable to both text and image which will also shift text and is not the requirement.

Comment: @AkashG you're right, so I made en edit now which will solve this problem with the text.

Comment: i think solvation is to use image button and use one image (of icon + text). what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will definately get the result:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="@drawable/wood"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<Button 
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
    android:text="HOME"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_home" 
    android:id="@+id/homebtn" 
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
  </Button>
```